# Getting error when trying to mask grayscale image based on how dark/light it is

Tags: python, opencv

The code I am trying to write should make the image feed grayscale, get the pixels that are quite dark, create a mask from those values and then use that mask to crop out the background.

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2

    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

    while(True):
        #get's the cameras video
        _, frame = cap.read()
        #Converts to grayscale
        grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        #black values
        white = ([255,255,255])
        gray= ([100,100,100])
        #Finds dark pixels
        mask = cv2.inRange(grayscale,gray,white)
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask)

        cv2.imshow('frame'.frame)
        cv2.imshow('mask',mask)
        cv2.imshow('res',res)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

and when I run the code I get this error mesage:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/molta/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/webcam.py", line 17, in         <module>
        mask = cv2.inRange(grayscale,gray,white)
    TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'lowerb'
```

I've tried searching for an answer, both on stackoverflow and google, but found nothing similar. I've also tried to understand what cv::UMat is, but sadly the documenation is poor to say the least.

Comment: cv has documentation for C/C++ and there should be information about `UMat` Maybe it means `Matrix` ?

Comment: if you have grayscale image then probably every pixel use only one value `255` not three `[255,255,255]`

Comment: looks like you a trying inRange with 3 channel RGB range, but previously you converted to grayscale, which is only 1 channel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from @furas comment, since your `grayscale` is a 2d array, only 1 value for `white` and `gray` is valid.

```
white = np.array(255)
gray = np.array(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to be `numpy.array`

```
white = np.array([255,255,255])
gray = np.array([100,100,100])
```

and then `cv2.inRange(grayscale, gray, white)` works

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.inRange` takes scalar bounds for a grayscaled image having size `M x N` with one channel in opencv. What you are doing above is for an image of size `M x N` with 3 channels.

So, Replace

```
white = ([255,255,255])
gray= ([100,100,100])
#Finds dark pixels
mask = cv2.inRange(grayscale, gray, white)
```

with

```
white = 255
gray = 100
#Finds dark pixels
mask = cv2.inRange(grayscale, gray, white)
```

Also, correct line `cv2.imshow('frame'.frame)` to `cv2.imshow('frame', frame)`.